# resultId in a multiple insert Mysql Node JS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using Node JS to do a insert in a MySql Database.

I checked the results of the INSERT and everything went well.

I am using at the result of the query, the var resultId to check the last id inserted on the database, but at this case I am inserting multiple rows into the database and my resultId has the value of the first inserted one.

Do in node Js exist something to use that I can see all the inserted resultId's ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can only get the ID for the first inserted row. If the primary key column is auto-incrementing, you could just increment the last insert ID to compute the inserted IDs for the second, third, etc. rows.

Comment: I got the idea but I have one point, that is a Server, if at the same time 2 instances try to add multiple rows, mysql know how to handle this 2 request ? I am afraid to at the same multiple insert, i have the id's 1, 2, 3 and 5. Because the 4 goes to the second request, is this possible?

Comment: I doubt it (for a single INSERT query), but you could use an explicit transaction if you wanted to be extra careful.